# Float type is rounded up

Tags: mysql

In Mysql, The float type can only be expressed up to six decimal places

```
create table Geolocation
(
    LATITUDE           float(20, 15)    not null,
    LONGITUDE          float(20, 15)    not null)
    comment 'geolocation' charset = utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO Geolocation VALUES('15.6517291','120.973719');

INSERT INTO Geolocation VALUES('15.651729123','120.973719123412');
```

result))

```
15.651729,120.97372
15.65173,120.97372
```

I wonder if the maximum number of digits in the data is 20 and the number below the decimal point is up to 15

expected))
15.6517291, 120.973719
15.651729123, 120.973719123412

Comment: This is non-portable according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html). Consider using `DOUBLE` instead. It's possible that the rounding is a function of the display, not the actual stored data.

Comment: if you care about a certain number of fixed decimals, use a decimal type.  otherwise use double.  there's no good use for float

Comment: It is not suitable for precise calculations and subject to rounding error and doesnot guarantee data will be stored with that level of precision. so its better to use `DOUBLE` datatype that can store more digits than float